# Firebase crashlytics won't detect app crashes when the app is running in the background

Tags: android, firebase, logging

I have an Android app where the majority of work is done in the background by its services. These services very often stop working / crash (the device will show the usual dialog that the app stopped working) but Firebase crashlytics doesn't record these crashes so I have no idea what causes them. The only crashes it does record are those that happen when the user is interacting with the app in the foreground.

How do you make Firebase record when services crash?

Comment: try updating firebase crash to latest version since there are update on firebase crash

Comment: You mean the ask in Android? I did.

Comment: No solution again? :(

Comment: sorry, seem I misunderstanding your problem case,  I think your problem is all error are not recorded to firebase :(

Comment: Have you found a solution?